# Creating Java EE application with SAML & ADFS for Single Sign On

Tags: jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, saml

I'm going to implement Single Sign On to a java application using ADFS as the Identity provider(IDP). Found this solution [SSO via OneLogin](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/java) and played around with its sample application. Apart from this, there is another solution [Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/products/opensaml-java.html).

I would like to know what is the best possible solution matching to my context.
Between, this is not a Spring application.

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to use JSP, according to the example you post ? JSF ? Which part do you need ? Some library to connect to those SSO services ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul. Yes, am using JSP. What I want to know is the best library/toolkit matches me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really don't want to use Spring Security SAML extension (which really only takes a few minutes to integrate it into your app) then you may need to look at

https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml or the Fedlet from OpenAM, however this requires much more additional coding than Spring Security SAML extension.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. Yes, this is what I have mentioned in the question and currently using.